# When check box is checked need to get edittext and after entering text getting the data from it ?How it is possible in android?

Tags: android, checkbox

> My requirement is as follows..
>
> I need to display some edittext fields if user is checked on checkbox
>   otherwise not to display it.
>
> If user is checked and entered data in edittext i need to get that
>   data how it is possible in android?

Comment: please be more specific and if possible, please provide some code

Answer (score 1):

Use this..

```
Your_Checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
//recording the click of the checkbox
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
{
    //testing if it is checked or unchecked
    if ( isChecked )
    {
        //if it is check
         EditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }else{
     EditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
});
```

then test you can have a button displayed also when the  check box is checked. When the button is pressed(such as enter)

then test..

```
if(EditText.isShown){
String userText = EditText.getText.toString();
}
```

Comment: exactly how it's done. just replace all EditText with your EditText variable.

Comment: after entering data into text box if i'm unchecking the checkbox i'm getting the data otherwise not getting.

Comment: Could you clarify this a little more?

Comment: after checking the checking the checkbox i'm getting the edittext and after entering the data into the edittext i'm writing the gettext() and also not getting the data from the edittext?